# Clickon function excluding one div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Everything you click on the that div I want to run the function `generate_clicked()`.

Here's my code I'm trying to use for tumblrgenerator.com:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#pane').click(function(){
        generate_clicked();
    });
</script>
```

But not even that code works and I'm not sure why? Only works when I use window

I want to use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).click(function(){
        generate_clicked();
    });
</script>
```

But exclude the text area `.preview` but I can't figure out how :(

In short how can I add a click function on everything but `.preview`?

Comment: You probably just need to wrap it in `$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: You need to wrap your code in [$(document).ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Always useful to include a snippet of markup.  Is 'pane' the id of your div containing all your text inputs?

Answer (score 0):

> In short how can I add a click function on everything but .preview

```
$('*').not('.preview').on('click', function () {
    generate_clicked();
});
```

Comment: This runs the function, but when I click on the .preview class element it still runs the function it's not ignoring it.

Comment: Using `*` might be heavy handed... Have you tried Silver_Clash's suggestion? Also, posting a fiddle would make it much easier for folks to offer working solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).click(function(ev){
if (!$(ev.target).hasClass('preview')) generate_clicked();
});
```